# Is it feasible to use constructed wetlands for greywater treatment in places where lakes freeze for more than half of the year?

Tags: waste-water, greywater

Let's say village-sized community discharging grey water from shower water, human and animal wastes and laundry water. These villages use modern detergent and medicine (especially antibiotics), have electricity, no sewage line.

The climate is similar to Alberta's. If there is a case study, that will be perfect.

Below: Every tiny speck in the green is a village; most of these villages are no more than 60 years old. I believe they are discharging grey waterdirectly into the environment.
[image]

Below: This is Heilongjiang province where these villages are located:
[image: location]

Comment: Can you add more detail? How much water, what type (shower, dishwater, industrial use, etc)? Is this an off-grid situation?

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy with human & animal waste involved is growing algae from the effluent to purify the water, recycling it then cheap and easy, uniits are insulated, LEDs via fiber optics climate controlled for 24x7 growing.

This supplies biodiesel to the village, enough for heat & to replace diesel use, vehicles to snowmobiles.

Nobody makes the bioreactors or growing units, too bad, it's an old idea, pre-WW2 algae growers had 50% oil species.